# grouping numpy arrays based on value similarity given the indices

Tags: python, numpy, grouping

I have a couple of numpy arrays:

```
orig = [[28021.22333333,  6585.53333333,     0. ],
 [28021.22333333,  6585.53333333,     0.        ],
 [26723.52333333,  6587.48666667,     0.        ],
 [26723.52333333,  6587.48666667,     0.        ],
 [26063.11,       13089.56,           0.        ],
 [26063.11,       13089.56,           0.        ],
 [27424.91,       13091.4,            0.        ],
 [27424.91,       13091.4,            0.        ],
 [28833.60333333, 12641.65333333,     0.        ],
 [28833.60333333, 12641.65333333,     0.        ],
 [26125.33,        7954.18166667,     0.        ],
 [26125.33,        7954.18166667,     0.        ],
 [26121.29666667,  7956.72633333,     0.        ],
 [26121.29666667,  7956.72633333,     0.        ],
 [26116.26,        7957.80833333,     0.        ],
 [26116.26,        7957.80833333,     0.        ],
 [26110.98333333,  7957.263,          0.        ],
 [26110.98333333,  7957.263,          0.        ],
 [26106.27,        7955.17333333,     0.        ],
 [26106.27,        7955.17333333,     0.        ],
 [26102.84,        7951.85733333,     0.        ],
 [26102.84,        7951.85733333,     0.        ]]
```

and

`idxs = [ 0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20, 21]`

`tri = [731, 703, 703, 731, 731, 731, 731, 693, 673, 699, 689, 731, 727, 731, 731, 731, 731, 731, 730]`

```
pnts = [[28035.61081192,  6657.82528209,  2800.  ],
 [27951.42292993,  6561.84728091,  2800.        ],
 [28076.63625815,  6536.92743701,  2800.        ],
 [28139.0775588,   6773.36600593,  2800.        ],
 [27990.76839321,  6805.17674429,  2800.        ],
 [27856.70943257,  6734.2138896,   2800.        ],
 [27799.62835447,  6593.68175023,  2800.        ],
 [27846.23402973,  6449.33687603,  2800.        ],
 [27974.71914494,  6368.71983786,  2800.        ],
 [28124.96408673,  6389.55224384,  2800.        ],
 [28226.66757706,  6502.08637967,  2800.        ],
 [28232.24142249,  6653.66627254,  2800.        ],
 [28382.4101748,  6673.10904354,  2800.        ],
 [28315.56368133,  6812.44564901,  2800.        ],
 [28197.8230677,   6912.54705367,  2800.        ],
 [28049.54675563,  6956.10481526,  2800.        ],
 [27896.37306654,  6935.58740108,  2800.        ],
 [27764.78712281,  6854.54245845,  2800.        ],
 [27677.54132953,  6726.98339422,  2800.        ]]
```

how to group now the values in `idxs`, `tri` and `pnts` based on the values of `idxs` which are indices to rows of `orig` so that they correspond to the same value per row in `orig`. For example I would like to get:

`idxs = [[0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [7], [8,9], [10,11], [12,13], [14,15], [17], [18], [20,21]]`

`tri = [[731, 703], [703, 731], [731, 731], [731], [693, 673], [699, 689], [731, 727], [731, 731], [731], [731], [731, 730]]`

and

```
pnts = [[[28035.61081192,  6657.82528209,  2800.  ],
     [27951.42292993,  6561.84728091,  2800.        ]],
     [[28076.63625815,  6536.92743701,  2800.        ],
     [28139.0775588,   6773.36600593,  2800.        ]],
     [[27990.76839321,  6805.17674429,  2800.        ],
     [27856.70943257,  6734.2138896,   2800.        ]],
     [[27799.62835447,  6593.68175023,  2800.        ]],
     [[27846.23402973,  6449.33687603,  2800.        ],
     [27974.71914494,  6368.71983786,  2800.        ]],
     [[28124.96408673,  6389.55224384,  2800.        ],
     [28226.66757706,  6502.08637967,  2800.        ]],
     [[28232.24142249,  6653.66627254,  2800.        ],
     [28382.4101748,  6673.10904354,  2800.        ]],
     [[28315.56368133,  6812.44564901,  2800.        ],
     [28197.8230677,   6912.54705367,  2800.        ]],
     [[28049.54675563,  6956.10481526,  2800.        ]],
     [[27896.37306654,  6935.58740108,  2800.        ]],
     [[27764.78712281,  6854.54245845,  2800.        ],
     [27677.54132953,  6726.98339422,  2800.        ]]]
```

I tried to `numpy.split()` but I couldn't really find the right condition to use. Also imagine that at the end I would have to apply the same on corresponding matrices with quite a few million inputs.

Comment: One way to quickly do that with minimal cognitive load would be to dump the data into sqlite (likely with tables in RAM) and do a straightforward SQL join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
eq = npi.group_by(orig[idxs])
print(eq.split(idxs))
print(eq.split(tri))
print(eq.split(pnts))
```

Obviously, you can sort them if you would like.

output:

```
#idxs
[array([0, 1]), array([20, 21]), array([8, 9]), array([14, 15]), array([2, 3]), array([17]), array([12, 13]), array([18]), array([4, 5]), array([7]), array([10, 11])]
#tri
[array([731, 703]), array([731, 730]), array([693, 673]), array([731, 731]), array([703, 731]), array([731]), array([731, 727]), array([731]), array([731, 731]), array([731]), array([699, 689])]
#pnts
[array([[28035.61081192,  6657.82528209,  2800.        ],
       [27951.42292993,  6561.84728091,  2800.        ]]), array([[27764.78712281,  6854.54245845,  2800.        ],
       [27677.54132953,  6726.98339422,  2800.        ]]), array([[27846.23402973,  6449.33687603,  2800.        ],
       [27974.71914494,  6368.71983786,  2800.        ]]), array([[28315.56368133,  6812.44564901,  2800.        ],
       [28197.8230677 ,  6912.54705367,  2800.        ]]), array([[28076.63625815,  6536.92743701,  2800.        ],
       [28139.0775588 ,  6773.36600593,  2800.        ]]), array([[28049.54675563,  6956.10481526,  2800.        ]]), array([[28232.24142249,  6653.66627254,  2800.        ],
       [28382.4101748 ,  6673.10904354,  2800.        ]]), array([[27896.37306654,  6935.58740108,  2800.        ]]), array([[27990.76839321,  6805.17674429,  2800.        ],
       [27856.70943257,  6734.2138896 ,  2800.        ]]), array([[27799.62835447,  6593.68175023,  2800.        ]]), array([[28124.96408673,  6389.55224384,  2800.        ],
       [28226.66757706,  6502.08637967,  2800.        ]])]
```

And if you want to convert them to lists (Note that numpy does not accept non-rectangular arrays like the ones above):

```
print(sorted([l.tolist() for l in eq.split(idxs)]))
```

output:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15], [17], [18], [20, 21]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan, thanks also for the `numpy_indexed` lib. It seems quite convenient to use.

Comment: one question `eq.split()` will put the data in consecutive order, however if in case that I did not have an index in `idxs` for one of the rows in `orig` how I could put an empty list in the corresponding position for example if 17 was not in my initial array my output array should be:  `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15], [], [18], [20, 21]]`

Comment: @ttsesm I cannot think of an easy fix. Specially sorting an empty array among bunch of arrays would not put it in correct place. Maybe a start would be to do `npi.group_by(orig)` and then sort and finally filter `idxs` ones from it. Because `eq` in above does not have your missing indexes in `idxs` to begin with even before splitting (note `orig[idxs]` in `eq`).

Comment: another solution that I was thinking is finding the missing indices as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608571/1476932 insert a default value, e.g. -1 and then do the grouping. It might be an overkill but as you said I cannot think another easy fix.