# PyTorch indexing: select complement of indices

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, matrix-indexing

Say I have a tensor and index:

```py
x = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5])
idx = torch.tensor([0,2,4])
```

If I want to select all elements **not** in the index, I can [manually define a Boolean mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518043/numpy-indexing-return-the-rest) like so:

```py
mask = torch.ones_like(x)
mask[idx] = 0

x[mask]
```

is there a more elegant way of doing this?

i.e. a syntax where I can directly pass the indices as opposed to creating a mask e.g. something like:

```py
x[~idx]
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a satisfactory solution to finding the complement of a **multi-dimensional tensor of indices** and finally implemented my own. It can work on cuda and enjoys fast parallel computation.

```py
def complement_idx(idx, dim):
    """
    Compute the complement: set(range(dim)) - set(idx).
    idx is a multi-dimensional tensor, find the complement for its trailing dimension,
    all other dimension is considered batched.
    Args:
        idx: input index, shape: [N, *, K]
        dim: the max index for complement
    """
    a = torch.arange(dim, device=idx.device)
    ndim = idx.ndim
    dims = idx.shape
    n_idx = dims[-1]
    dims = dims[:-1] + (-1, )
    for i in range(1, ndim):
        a = a.unsqueeze(0)
    a = a.expand(*dims)
    masked = torch.scatter(a, -1, idx, 0)
    compl, _ = torch.sort(masked, dim=-1, descending=False)
    compl = compl.permute(-1, *tuple(range(ndim - 1)))
    compl = compl[n_idx:].permute(*(tuple(range(1, ndim)) + (0,)))
    return compl
```

Example:

```
>>> import torch
>>> a = torch.rand(3, 4, 5)
>>> a
tensor([[[0.7849, 0.7404, 0.4112, 0.9873, 0.2937],
         [0.2113, 0.9923, 0.6895, 0.1360, 0.2952],
         [0.9644, 0.9577, 0.2021, 0.6050, 0.7143],
         [0.0239, 0.7297, 0.3731, 0.8403, 0.5984]],

        [[0.9089, 0.0945, 0.9573, 0.9475, 0.6485],
         [0.7132, 0.4858, 0.0155, 0.3899, 0.8407],
         [0.2327, 0.8023, 0.6278, 0.0653, 0.2215],
         [0.9597, 0.5524, 0.2327, 0.1864, 0.1028]],

        [[0.2334, 0.9821, 0.4420, 0.1389, 0.2663],
         [0.6905, 0.2956, 0.8669, 0.6926, 0.9757],
         [0.8897, 0.4707, 0.5909, 0.6522, 0.9137],
         [0.6240, 0.1081, 0.6404, 0.1050, 0.6413]]])
>>> b, c = torch.topk(a, 2, dim=-1)
>>> b
tensor([[[0.9873, 0.7849],
         [0.9923, 0.6895],
         [0.9644, 0.9577],
         [0.8403, 0.7297]],

        [[0.9573, 0.9475],
         [0.8407, 0.7132],
         [0.8023, 0.6278],
         [0.9597, 0.5524]],

        [[0.9821, 0.4420],
         [0.9757, 0.8669],
         [0.9137, 0.8897],
         [0.6413, 0.6404]]])
>>> c
tensor([[[3, 0],
         [1, 2],
         [0, 1],
         [3, 1]],

        [[2, 3],
         [4, 0],
         [1, 2],
         [0, 1]],

        [[1, 2],
         [4, 2],
         [4, 0],
         [4, 2]]])
>>> compl = complement_idx(c, 5)
>>> compl
tensor([[[1, 2, 4],
         [0, 3, 4],
         [2, 3, 4],
         [0, 2, 4]],

        [[0, 1, 4],
         [1, 2, 3],
         [0, 3, 4],
         [2, 3, 4]],

        [[0, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 3],
         [1, 2, 3],
         [0, 1, 3]]])
>>> al = torch.cat([c, compl], dim=-1)
>>> al
tensor([[[3, 0, 1, 2, 4],
         [1, 2, 0, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [3, 1, 0, 2, 4]],

        [[2, 3, 0, 1, 4],
         [4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 0, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],

        [[1, 2, 0, 3, 4],
         [4, 2, 0, 1, 3],
         [4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
         [4, 2, 0, 1, 3]]])
>>> al, _ = al.sort(dim=-1)
>>> al
tensor([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],

        [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],

        [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the single-line expression:

```py
x[np.setdiff1d(range(len(x)), idx)]
```

Though it seems also not elegant:).